# Ordenação na query - Deixar o ultimo cadastro em primeiro e depois ordenar por um campo

Tags: order-by, sqlfiddle

Estou tendo que criar uma query que me retorne os dados ordenados por um campo especifico, por exemplo nome, mas a primeira linha de retorno deve ser o ultimo id. Tem como fazer isso com sql?

Vamo supor que eu tenha o tabela usuario:

```
id    nome
1     João
2     Marcelo
3     André
4     Vanessa
```

O retorno deve ser:

```
id    nome
4     Vanessa
3     André
1     João
2     Marcelo
```

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia para isso.

Segue um [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63cb7a/1)

Comment: @MarceloDiniz essa é a explicação inclusive coloquei na minha resposta: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4436.union-x-union-all-pt-br.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possível solução:

```
SELECT
   id,nome
FROM
   usuario
JOIN
   (SELECT MAX(id) AS ultimo FROM usuario) AS dummy
ORDER BY id != ultimo, nome
```

Explicação:

1. A subquery `(SELECT MAX(id) AS ultimo FROM minha.Base.minhaTabela) AS dummy` faz com que o `id` maior seja retornado para todas as linhas, sob o nome de coluna `ultimo`.
2. O `ORDER BY` primeiro ordena pelo `id` diferente do `id maior`, ou seja, `false` para o maior `id`, o que torna este a primeira linha da query.
3. tirando o caso especial do `id`, a ordenação é feita pelo nome.

> Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcf1d2/1)**

Answer (score 2):

Uma tabela auxiliar pode ser usada para esse cenário:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id int, nome nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO #temp (id, nome)
    SELECT id, nome from tabela where id = (select max(id) from tabela)
INSERT INTO #temp
    SELECT id, nome from tabela where id <> (select max(id) from tabela) order by nome
SELECT id, nome FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Eu só não sei se é a melhor opção, nesse caso, usando uma tabela auxiliar, não iria consumir muito mais recursos do servidor do que das outras formas que foram colocadas? Não que a sua não resolva, dai a questão é consumo de servidor e tempo de resposta. Valew

Comment: Até ver a resposta de @Bacco eu não sabia se seria possível fazer sem uma tabela auxiliar. A dele com certeza é a melhor (razão pela qual eu votei nela). Mas como tecnicamente essa resposta também resolve o problema, decidi deixá-la aqui em vez de remover para o caso de alguma outra pessoa encontre um cenário onde uma tabela extra é necessária.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT usr.* 
FROM   usuario AS usr, 
       (SELECT Max(id) AS maxid 
        FROM   usuario) AS src 
ORDER  BY src.maxid != usr.id, 
          usr.nome
```

Explicação:

Primeiro definimos em uma subquery qual é o maior `ID`, e o disponibilizamos para consulta na query principal.

Depois utilizamos uma comparação diretamente na cláusula `ORDER BY`.

Resultado:

```
| ID |    NOME |
|----|---------|
|  4 | Vanessa |
|  3 |   André |
|  1 |    João |
|  2 | Marcelo |
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou sem problemas, e nesse caso, diferendo do que a @Maria passou eu entendi o pq não retornou o ultimo registro duas vezes. Agradeço

Answer (score 0):

é só utilizar algo assim `order by id desc`

só complementando para os que não conseguiram tentar entender

```
SELECT *
FROM teste
ORDER BY id DESC, nome ASC
```

Comment: Não é tão simples assim! Não sei se entendeu, mas eu tenho que retornar os dados ordenados pelo nome, mas o primeiro registro retornado deve ser o ultimo inserido na tabela.

Comment: simples ORDER BY id DESC, nome ASC

Comment: Eu entendi o que vc colocou, mas infelizmente não da certo dessa forma. Mas ainda assim eu agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: opa tranquilo espero que tenha conseguido resolver

Answer (score 0):

Assim:

O primeiro Select pega as informações do último registro, já o segundo faz a ordenação total pelo campo nome, ao uniar as tabelas ele já faz o que a pergunta espera a união das duas SQL, eliminando inclusive o código que se repete!
Porque não repete com um `union` ele faz um distinct para não haver repetição, segundo [link microsoft](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4436.union-x-union-all-pt-br.aspx), está muito bem explicado.

```
SELECT id, nome FROM (
      SELECT id, nome FROM testdb.tabela30 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
) AS tabelaidmax
union
SELECT id, nome from (SELECT id, nome FROM testdb.tabela30 ORDER BY nome asc
) as tabelanomeasc
```

Comment: @Otto Infelizmente sua resposta não da certo, da uma olhada no sqlFiddle que eu coloquei na pergunta. E Maria se vc puder representar um sqlFiddle e mandar, que eu não conseguir representar, mas ainda assim agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Comment: Em relação ao SQLFiddle o meu está dando erro está falando que esta com problemas técnicos você conhece outro

Comment: E com esse eu exemplo funcionou sim. Simples pelo que entendi, a primeira query retorna somente o ultimo registro e na segunda ordenado pelo nome. Agora não entendi o pq não trouxe o ultimo registro duas vezes.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz, boa pergunta, quando você coloca só `UNION` ele tem o trabalho de retirar os repetidos se você por exemplo colocar `UNION ALL` ele vai trazer inclusive os repetidos.

Comment: Realmente não lembrava disso do ´UNION´. Já tinha lido, mas não me lembrava mesmo, agradeço pelas respostas e pela pesquisa.